# Get structure of RDF graph by SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs

How can I get only triples which represent graph structure - class and properties hierarchy (i.e. without individuals, property values)?

Comment: For class hierarchy: `CONSTRUCT WHERE 
 {?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?sup }` Analogous for property hierarchy using the predicate `rdfs:subPropertyOf`

Comment: Or do it in one query: `CONSTRUCT 
  { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
  }
WHERE
  { VALUES ?p { rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:subPropertyOf }
          ?s  ?p  ?o
  }`

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that I need also rdf:type, owl:class :domain :range  triples.

Comment: Ok, but you asked for the class hierarchy... Then simply add the other triples to the CONSTRUCT query: `CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o . } WHERE { VALUES ?p { rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:domain rdfs:range} ?s ?p ?o }` I don't see why you need `<cls> rdf:type owl:Class` triples. But if you need, add it to the `CONSTRUCT` query as well using a `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need rdf:type, owl:class and etc. triplets. So that is my variant:

```
PREFIX rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

select ?s ?p ?o 
where
{
    {
        graph <http://graph.org/gr>
        {       
            ?s rdf:type ?o.
            ?s ?p ?o.
        }
        FILTER
            (?o IN (owl:Class, owl:DatatypeProperty, owl:AnnotationProperty, owl:ObjectProperty, owl:DataRange, owl:Ontology,
            owl:DataRange,owl:DeprecatedClass,owl:DeprecatedProperty,owl:OntologyProperty,rdfs:Class,owl:Restriction,owl:InverseFunctionalProperty,
            owl:FunctionalProperty,owl:AllDisjointClasses,rdf:Property, rdfs:Datatype )
            )
}
UNION
{
        graph <http://graph.org/gr>
        {
            ?s ?p ?o.
        }
        FILTER
            (?p IN (rdfs:subClassOf,rdfs:subPropertyOf,rdfs:domain,rdfs:range,rdfs:label,rdfs:comment,rdfs:member,
            rdf:first,rdf:rest,owl:allValuesFrom,owl:someValuesFrom,owl:AnnotationProperty,owl:equivalentClass,
            owl:equivalentProperty,owl:hasValue,owl:OntologyProperty,owl:SymmetricProperty,owl:TransitiveProperty,
            owl:versionInfo,owl:priorVersion,owl:oneOf,owl:maxCardinality,owl:minCardinality,owl:inverseOf,
            owl:incompatibleWith,owl:intersectionOf,owl:imports,owl:backwardCompatibleWith,owl:AllDifferent,
            owl:differentFrom,owl:disjointWith,owl:distinctMembers,owl:complementOf,owl:cardinality,owl:unionOf,owl:onProperty))
        }
}
```

Comment: Next time should clarify this in your question. It sounds more like you're querying for all schema axioms of an OWL ontology. You're still missing axioms like `?p rdf:type owl:FunctionalProperty` etc.

Comment: Moreover, you asked for triples, thus, I don't see why you're using a `SELECT` query.

Comment: Sorry, I confused the triples with solutions.